# VMs in Cloud Foundry

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry

Assuming I have a data center where cloud foundry is installed on top of a IAAS layer - say for instance VMWare VShpere. I assume PCF creates a number of VMs on top of this and each VM is used for a specific purpose - eg: few for building buildpacks , some for hosting actual app instance etc. I heard somewhere that there are 20 VMs created. So assuming there is only one availability zone for my data center , would the number of VMs that created be always 20 irrespective of size & volume of underlying hardware? Please can you also clarify how many VMs get created and what is the purpose of these VMs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy all the components that comprise the Cloud Foundry service in a single VM (see [PCF Dev](https://docs.pivotal.io/pcf-dev/)) or across thousands of VMs for massive scale and fault tolerance.

If you are using Pivotal Ops Manager to deploy Pivotal Cloud Foundry, the standard deployment includes several additional pieces, and may have a minimum of 20 or so VMs.  Since 20 is a lot to enumerate, I recommend consulting Pivotal Cloud Foundry documentation or discussing these questions with your Pivotal sales representative.

Comment: Thanks Amit , when using OPS Manager , does it automatically create 20 VMs? Is there a way to configure more VM instances when deploying PCF using OPS Manager. Please can you also help in letting me know what each VM performs?

Comment: I'm at the cf summit too. Saw that you are a speaker on bosh day :-)